# Turning a .java "installer" to an .jar executable

Tags: java, windows-installer

```
public static void moveSQLite(){
        File source = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\System.Data.SQLite"); // Specify initial path
        File target = new File("C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\\GAC_64"); // Desired path

        // If the source location exists, delete the any old source files
        // and copy the entire directory of the source to the target location
        if(source.exists()){
            System.out.println("Installing SQLite Database.");
            try {
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(target);
                System.out.println("Deleting previous versions of System.Data.SQLite");
                System.out.println("\"" + source + "\"" + " was successfully"
                        + " copied to " + "\"" + target + "\"");
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, target);
                System.out.println("SQLite database has been installed.");
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        // Otherwise prompt the user that the source directory does not exist
        }else{
            System.out.println("SQLite not found - are you sure you have it in the right directory?");
        }
    }
```

Above is one of the methods for my "installer" for my plugin for Revit. It's not so much an installer but a script that moves particular folders and files to destinations on the host's computer.

It is my first time doing "software development" for Java, so most of the software development practices are unknown to me - my questions are: how do I package this as a .jar or .msi, preferably with a simple command-line interface so that the user can:

1. Select source path for where the installer package is (i.e. on the desktop)
2. Select target path for where Revit is installed

The installation process should be as seamless as possible. This script basically replaces dragging and dropping - and I have that essentially done.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your project in eclipse. Export -> Runnable jar and select main class where this logic is implemented. This will export runnable jar file.

Also, Install4j is very good option for packaging, installing and it also has support for multiple OS's. I personally has used install4j multiple times( for platforms like Windows and Mac), it's pretty simple and configurable.
Please refer to below URL,

http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html

Comment: For our uses we don't really need a commercial solution. It's really as simple as dragging a couple folders to two directories! I also have the back-end stuff completed - I just need a way to package that as something users can double click and automatically run the script. Turning what I wrote (which is in .java) into a .msi or .jar is all I am asking for.

Comment: Oops.. Skimped over it -> sorry! Will I need to change things like System.out.println() to Console.out.... (or its console-equivalent method in Java)?

Comment: You can still go ahead with System.out.println() to console out, however i would suggest to use logger like log4j.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Main-Class:` in your manifest and the jar will become executable using the `java -jar myapp.jar` syntax

See [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for more background information and instructions on how to do this.

Assume Installer.class has a `main()` method and is your applications entry point.  Your manifest might look something like this:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0 
>   Created-By: 1.6.0_45-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
>   Main-Class: com.foo.Installer

Then running `java -jar installer.jar` will invoke `com.foo.Installer`

Under some operating systems, double clicking on the jar will also launch the main class.

**Edit** If you want to turn your `.jar` into a `.exe`, then what I've listed above is not enough.  In that case, as mentioned in other answers, you'll need to use something like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) or one of the commercial alternatives.